# Can I create multiple wallets using the same hardware device (Ledger Nano S is this case)?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I just recently got a Ledger Nano S and am getting familiarized with the Monero GUI app and the Ledger Monero app which I installed on the Nano using Ledger Live.

If I choose "Create a new wallet from hardware device" will it create new keys, mnemonic and XMR address? This would mean that when I choose 'Restore a wallet' next time, I can choose to load different key files and therefore .

Comment: A given 24 word Ledger mnemonic seed always corresponds to a certain XMR public address. It logically follows that, unless your 24 word Ledger mnemonic seed changes (e.g. you use a Ledger device with a different mnemonic seed), you will always generate the same wallet.

Comment: So each hardware device/wallet has a (factory) preset mnemonic seed that can't be changed? If as you say "A given 24 word Ledger mnemonic seed always corresponds to a certain XMR public address" then each hardware device/wallet can only have one wallet? I'm confused with all these options of creating wallets, 'sub-wallets' and accounts. What happens when I create another account once logged in? It shows a different XMR address.

Comment: Accounts are just a housekeeping thing inside a wallet. You have one wallet that can contain multiple accounts and multiple subaddresses.

Comment: More details on accounts and subaddresses: https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/

Comment: So an accounts or subaddress is like or functions like a shielded address or transparent address? Would an analogy like checking account for a subaddress used to send/receive and a savings or MM account for the primary account which is used to send/receive only from a subaddress? And is a subaddress an actual XMR address that acts like a proxy?

Comment: No. Monero does not have "shielded address or transparent address". Accounts are just a way to organize your wallet addresses and subaddresses act like normal Monero addresses but allow you to have multiple addresses per wallet. Before subaddresses were implemented, you could only have one address per wallet. See the link I posted above as it explains very well.

Comment: "So each hardware device/wallet has a (factory) preset mnemonic seed that can't be changed?" <= No. The 24 word Ledger mnemonic seed is randomly generated upon initially setting up the device. If desired, you can also generate a new seed. Hopefully it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: jtgrassie, so a subaddress is an actual address in the Monero network, meaning if I send xmr to a subaddress, it does not get redirected and stored in the main/primary address but rather it is stored in that subaddress until I manually transfer/send it to the main/primary address? Can I move xmr between the main/primary address and subaddresses within the wallet or is it recorded in the network?

Comment: dEBRUYNE, thanks for the clarification. How do I generate a new seed in the wallet/Monero GUI? Do I have to delete the current wallet and create a new one? Does the xmr address remain the same? I notice that when I installed the Monero app from Ledger Live, it already had the xmr address.